# Angular reactive Form Control default value has no impact

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a question concerning angular reactive form. When I want to set default values for my form controls it does not work in the HTML.

**TS:**

```
    // set form controls
    this.DataService.TabArchivForm = this.fb.group({
      ArchiveControl: [true],
      DateChannelControl: [Date.now(), Validators.required]
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tab_main" [formGroup]="this.DataService.TabArchivForm">  
  <mat-form-field class="field_width">
    <mat-label class="Inputlabel">Date</mat-label>
    <input class="Inputvalue" matInput id="date" [formControl]="this.DataService.TabArchivForm.controls.DateChannelControl" [matDatepicker]="dp3" required>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dp3 disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-error *ngIf="this.DataService.TabArchivForm.controls.DateChannelControl.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-checkbox color="primary" [formControl]="this.DataService.TabArchivForm.controls.ArchivControl" id="archive">Archive</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

I don't know why it does not set the default values for the HTML elements. The checkbox is unchecked and the input field from the date picker is empty as well. Am I missing something?
Thanks for answers!

Comment: [formControl]="DataService.TabArchivForm.controls.DateChannelControl" remove this

Comment: But then I can't access the value from the form control for the date picker and I need to read the value in the final process

Comment: Nope, no error in the console Sir

Comment: Yes, just tested it out and it did not work either ... what bothers me the most is the fact that not even the checkbox boolean value has an impact ...

When I remove the formControl from the checkbox element and use [checked]="this.DataService.TabArchivForm.controls.ArchivControl.value" it works

Comment: if it possible can you create stackbliz?

Comment: Instead of `[formControl]="this.DataService.TabArchivForm.controls.DateChannelControl"` try `formControlName="DateChannelControl"`

Comment: Moxxi: Yes I already tried this, but it failed as well
@Chellappanவ I tried it in one component on stackblitz and it seems to work there, could the main cause be, that I use a fromgroup from another component provider?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqhwer?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: How you are using from group from another component passing down as input property or defining service?

Comment: The DataService is a provider component that has global variables and methods implemented, I outsourced the form groups in the DataService, so that I can access the forms from every component I want.
I'm importing the DataService in my component and there have never been problems like this